# C++ Alternative to OpenProcess() (Program not willing to grant me permission)

Tags: c++, windows

I'm fairly new to C++ so my question is: Is there an alternative to OpenProcess()?The game does not let me get access to it, tried asking for smaller access than PROCESS_ACCESS_ALL since that might be a huge red flag. But here's my source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <Windows.h>



int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, "Growtopia");
    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Unable to find window process" << std::endl;
        Sleep(2500);
        exit(-1);
    }
    DWORD pID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pID);
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pID);
    if (!hProc)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Unable to gain access to window" << std::endl;
        Sleep(2500);
        exit(-1);
    }



        return 0;
}
```

PS: The game I'm trying to gain access to is Growtopia if you couldn't find it out by the FindWindow() function :)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: My purpouse of the program is to edit a value of an adress

Comment: have you tried running your program as administrator?

Comment: If you want someone to look at your code, include it in the question please.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm assuming running the build in VS should automatically run it as an Administrator? Shouldn't be the problem though because I tried OpenProcess() on other windows and it worked just fine. I'm guessing they have some kind of anticheat that prevents it.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Will do next time :) Had a little bit off trouble getting it in the code format so I pasted it in pastebin. But someone who was kind enough edited my post so it is fixed.

Comment: So you think there is another API that does exactly the same thing as `OpenProcess()` but without the permission check? Why would anyone build such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My purpouse of the program is to edit a value of an adress

That requires the use of [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx), which requires `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` and `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` permissions to the target process:

```
HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, false, pID);
```

To open a process with those permissions, the calling thread needs the `"SeDebugPrivilege"` privilege enabled, which means it has to be running as a user that is allowed to obtain debug privileges, such as an admin.

Run your app as a debug user (or dynamically impersonate such a user), then use [`OpenThreadToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379296.aspx) to open the calling thread's current access token and adjust it with [`AdjustTokenPrivileges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx) to make sure the `"SeDebugPrivilege"` privilege is active, before then calling `OpenProcess()`:

[Changing Privileges in a Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717797.aspx)

[How to obtain a handle to any process with SeDebugPrivilege](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131065)